# Unwanted Rainbow icon on pygame

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, webcam, raspberry-pi2

I'm currently working on a pygame script, which is basically displaying an user interface over a webcam stream. This app is running on raspberry pi, on dual screen via fbcp.

I noticed that a strange rainbow square icon did recently appeared in the upper right corner of the screen.

Looking like this, but smaller :
[image]

What is it ? How can i remove the display of this icon ?

Thank you !

Comment: where is your code? how can we help without seeing what images you use

Comment: Providing the minimalist working exemple would be solving the issue :)
I was hoping someone who did already see ths icon could share his knowledge.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you should be providing the minimal working example

Comment: Look at it yourself ;) As my question is not about code but process, mcve seems quite irrelevant to me.

Comment: I would agree that this question doesn't need MVCE, but it might indicate that this isn't a programming question but more a question about software.

Comment: So ... Thank you everyone. (joke)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself :

This icon is shown by the raspberry itself to inform about under-voltage issue.
To prevent it from showing, solve the power issue, or remove rpi warnings (not a safe approach), by adding to /boot/config.txt :

```
avoid_warnings=2
```

Comment: If this answered your question you should be able to accept this answer, hence informing others that the question has an viable answer.

Comment: +Ted Klein Bergman : I can't, as it takes 2 days before i can accept my own answer.
Damn, i start hating the moderation system, that push users to give wrong advice (i.e. mcve for each question), or to ask such an impossible task. We are here to help and share, not to be picky about everything. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't aware of that. It's not about being picky but to help the community. I believe your question is viable and an accepted answer would help quickly distinguish unanswered questions from answered, thus helping the community. As of MVCE, more often than not people need to see code to find a problem/solution. Your example didn't but what the users tried to do was to make your question complete, in the belief that it wasn't. It was not to be picky but to help the community and others to benefit from your question. It can sometimes be annoying but it's often with good intend.

Comment: To be honest, i don't consider good intends. Only goods results.
But I don't blame you, as everyone that plays moderator can do such a mistake.